# How to change the color of a group of Text inside a Column using inheritance?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is a `Column` and a group of `Text` inside. The goal is to change the color of all the `Text` without explicitly specifying it on each one of them.

For instance, one approach could be done by wrapping the `Column` around some `Widget` with a property like `textColor` such that when its value is changed, all the `Text` inside the `Column` would inherit such a color.

This behavior is very similar to how the property of `textColor` works in a `ListTile` widget where you don't have to explicitly specify the color on the `Text` widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DefaultTextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextStyle-class.html) for that.
Here is a small example where all Text widgets in the Column have the color red.

```dart
const DefaultTextStyle(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text('Hello World'),
      Text('Random Text...'),
    ],
  ),
);
```